# A word for someone who is unwanted, a pariah, someone left to fend on their own?

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing a book and I need a word to call a character who is punished for becoming part of a group of people who are socially rejected and unwanted. They are left to fend for themselves on the street.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you already have one.  "Pariah".

If you're looking for a similar word with less of the specific connotations of 'Pariah', then the word 'outcast' would probably suit your needs.

One who is forbidden from a group out of shame could also be said to be "banished" from the group.

Comment: also "shunned".

Comment: Also "sent to Coventry": http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sent-to-coventry.html

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [*ostracized*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ostracised), it fits perfectly:

> ostracize, ostracise [ˈɒstrəˌsaɪz] vb (tr)
>   1. to exclude or banish (a person) from a particular group, society, etc.
>   2. (Historical Terms) (in ancient Greece) to punish by temporary exile
>
> [from Greek ostrakizein to select someone for banishment by voting on
>   potsherds; see ostracon]

Answer (score 2):

One particular term for individuals who are outcasts is *[untouchable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/untouchable?q=untouchable)*, used as a noun.

> a member of the lowest-caste Hindu group or a person outside the caste system, contact with whom is traditionally held to defile members of higher castes.

While often applied to the *Dalit* community in South Asia, this term is used for various groups in other countries as well.  See discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untouchability).

Answer (score 2):

Please consider:

> **outcast** 1: one that is cast out or refused acceptance (as by society) : pariah

from m-w.com

Comment: This is almost too obvious to post, since in m-w "pariah" mentions "outcast" in the 2nd definition.

Answer (score 1):

*Leper* would work. Note the 2nd definition from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leper):

Definition of LEPER

1
: a person affected with leprosy

2
: a person shunned for moral or social reasons

You could also describe the character as a *social leper.*

Answer (score 1):

"Untouchable" was one of the suggestions, and it fits nicely, especially with ethnic connotations.

On the other hand, "untouchable" can also have a nearly opposite meaning, someone or something that cannot be equaled, especially in a competitive setting.  It was also the nickname of group of Federal agents in the US because they were not susceptible to graft.

It's all in the context.

Answer (score -1):

An *interloper* is a person who becomes involved in a place or situation where they are not wanted or are considered not to belong.